# Can someone clarify Raphael's documentation? (or know a place in which someone already has done it)

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I´m working with Raphael, and I think that  I´m using it in a way that does not take advantage of some features that seems to be useful.

For example, I´m trying to add a listener on a Set (a group of elements), in a way that on mouse over on any of those elements, the script triggers an animation on the whole set.

When you add a listener to a set, Raphael adds the listener to each of the elements and animates them separately.

Like you see in this example http://jsfiddle.net/4VYHe/3/ in wich I want that all the rectangles in the same set (set = horizontal groups of 10 rectangles), change the color attribute on mouse over on any of them.

I have found a few methods in the raphael documentation that i think must help to achive this. But I´m having a hard time understanding how these methods work.

For example:

- the eve object(http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#eve)
- the Element.animateWith() method (http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animateWith)
- the Raphael.animation() method (http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.animation)

The Raphael Library seems to be really powerful and I really want to get it work properly, I don´t want to write all kinds of diferent javascript hacks, because I think that these tools have to get the work done in a more elegant way.

If you think that I´m using the wrong library I´m still open to all kinds of advices. 
Thank you in advance.

---EDIT---

This is a working example (http://jsfiddle.net/4VYHe/6/). But this is a hack with lack of efficiency and elegancy. I want something that uses the correct tools on the correct way.

There is some information on this page. http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2#PAGETOP . A couple of examples, but nothing that explain how things work in Raphael.

Comment: A set in Rapheal is confusing, I think you, like me, first thought a set is like a g element (group) in SVG. However as you found out it's more like an array of objects. I believe it has to do with the difference between SVG and VML (VML is used for Internet Explorer versions < 9 which don't support SVG, yes IE ruins it for everyone again).

If you don't need IE < 9 support you might want to take a look at d3.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/4VYHe/9/), I think it is doing what you are looking for. The fundamental difference is that you want to call animate on the set, rather than `this`. It appears that when you add a handler to a set, `this` refers to the individual elements in the set (which are iterated over to assign the handler), and not the set itself.

Note that I pulled the handler functions out into the getHoverHandler function:

```
function getHoverHandler(fillColor) {
     var cSet = set;

     return function(){
          cSet.animate({fill: fillColor}, 300);
      };
}

set.hover(getHoverHandler('#000'),
          getHoverHandler('#FFF'));
```

in order to break the closure. If you try to do it like this:

```
set.hover(function(){
            set.animate({fill: '#000'}, 300)
        }, function(){
            set.animate({fill: '#FFF'}, 300)
        });
```

as you loop through, set will keep changing, and the closures will maintain awareness of this. As a result, all handlers will be acting on the last row of boxes.

If you don't understand javascript closures, you might want to look at this [article](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies). It is old, but in pretty simple language, and it helped me as I have tried to get my head around them.

Comment: Thank you. I finally am understanding where the problem is in this particular case. I´m still new to programming and there are some concepts that you learn in practice. However I still want to understand some Raphael features that I think could help to get trough these problems. I´m going to use the solution that you gave me about the hover case and always keep an eye on which direction the this keyword is pointing to.

Comment: And which do you think is the best way to reference the sets in other parts of the aplications, meaning, to make the sets aviable, of some way, for using them on things like remove the hover on click event. I´ve atached an Id to each element on the set with a refference to it, for example setA_1 setA_2 setB_1 setB_2. But i don´t know if this is the best idea.

Comment: It is hard to say what would be best without knowing more about the application, but you might want to use jQuery and store them with the paper using something like `$('#rects').data('set_' + index, set)`. Then they would be available sort of globally. You may be able to use Raphael's Element.data(), but not sure in this case if you would really want them associated with a Raphael element.

Comment: Yes, i´m going to accept your answer because It was really helpful for me. But I was hoping for someone that could give me an answer to the original question itself, about the clarification of the Raphael library.

Answer (score 5):

Kreek is absolutely correct in this comment above. Sets are a workaround for the inconsistencies between SVG and VML.

In your example above, you're running into the same issue that you were facing in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117516/apply-hover-event-in-raphael-on-a-set-of-paths). Using **this** in an anonymous function will almost always not work in the way you expect, as **this** won't be referring to what you think it is. Have a look at [this discussion](http://thomasdavis.github.com/tutorial/anonymous-functions.html), particularly the first two comments in the comments section. (As an aside, the commenter uses "self" as the reference to "this", which is much better than my "that", which goes to show there's always someone doing it better than yourself)

Anyway, with that in mind, I've [cloned](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/4F23u/) your fiddle, wrapped your set in an object, and put the events into the object constructor. By doing this, the event can then refer to **that.set** and animate all objects in the set at the same time.

It's a small but fundamental concept that will aid you throughout any Raphael (or javascript) development you do.

This doesn't answer your question directly, but hopefully clarifies some of the issues you seem to be discovering. I can't really comment on the animation calls you've mentioned, but I do think that Raphael as a library is definitely worth persevering with.

N.

Comment: Yes, now I have a better understanding on where the problem is in this particular case. In the maps example, I was able to see the problem after you help me with it. But now I understand the solution, and how the solution works. Thank you again!!

Comment: that's crazy ... but it works ... I copy/pasted your _setObj_ function into my code, and used _new setObj(my_set_#)_ for each of my sets, and voila it worked.