# when using "this", functions lose context - Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am looping through an object and creating circles in Raphael. On each circle I create, I attach a click event and a mouseover event. However, when I use "this" to move the circle to the front, this.toFront() , for example, then my .click function does not work. If I comment on the this.toFront() then my click function works as expected.

Can you help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

```
//dummy variables for example
var x_coord = '31';
var y_coord = '50';
var diameter = '80';
var opportunityUrl = 'http://www.google.com';
var fillColorStart = '#000';
var fillColorEnd = '#FF0000';

var p = paper.circle(x_coord, y_coord, diameter)
.data("i", i)
.click(function() {
   alert(opportunityUrl);
})
.mouseover(function() {
   this.toFront();
})
.attr({"fill": "90-"+fillColorStart+":5-"+fillColorEnd+":95","fill-opacity": 0.5})
.glow({color: "#4b4b4b", width: 7})
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure how Raphael works entirely, I think `this` in this case refers to the window object. This would break the event chain, which presumably breaks all of the events on an object, which would lead to your `.click()` not working as well.

Comment: ok cool. Any thoughts on how you woudl then target that element without breaking the event chain?

Comment: Perhaps add the event handler after you've created the object and stored a reference to it in `p`? You could then do `p.toFront();` instead of `this.toFront();`.

Comment: From the documentation, http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html, it looks like `this` inside the `mouseover` function is equal to `p.node`, i.e. the DOM elmeent, therefore, as @ElliotBonneville said you need to use the p variable at that point.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If this answer was helpful, please upvote it, and if it solved your problem, could you mark it as the solution? (with the checkmark to the left of the answer)

Comment: thanks! I tried to upvote it, but dont have enough reputation points yet. I will in the future.

Comment: Peter you don't need to upvote, just click on the big tick that's waiting to turn green just like the hulk :)

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8167903/981898). Basically, the `this` pointer within the anonymous function doesn't refer to what you think it does.

In your case, doing what Elliot says above is probably the easiest solution.